# Conditional statement between columns and rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'd like to create to column, that creates a value based on if-statement between values in the same row and, if needed, in the rows above. 
I have a constant A and `df`

```
A = 0.5
          FID_1          b          c        d            e
75907       nan 33021647.00   27014.12 27014.12        1.00
75858 159510.00 32888862.00   16532.64 28797.05        0.57
75859 159510.00 32888862.00   12264.41 28797.05        0.43
75795       nan 32869718.00   24218.16 24218.16        1.00
75518       nan 32574894.00   13304.45 13304.45        1.00
```

I'd like to create another column called `f` that will tell me if the value in `e` is greater than A or not for the given value in `b`. If that is correct, than the value is 1.

Example for the above df:

```
          FID_1          b          c        d            e    f
75907       nan 33021647.00   27014.12 27014.12        1.00    1
75858 159510.00 32888862.00   16532.64 28797.05        0.57    1
75859 159510.00 32888862.00   12264.41 28797.05        0.43    0
75795       nan 32869718.00   24218.16 24218.16        1.00    1
75518       nan 32574894.00   13304.45 13304.45        1.00    1
```

What is more tricky is, if I change the value of `A` to `0.6`. In this case, I'd like to see for each number in `b`, if the first row of the value in `b` has a value in `e` greater than `A` and if not, i'd like to see for the second row of the same value `sum` of the values in `e` and check if it is greater than A. The `df` with `A=0.6` look like this:

```
          FID_1          b          c        d            e    f
75907       nan 33021647.00   27014.12 27014.12        1.00    1
75858 159510.00 32888862.00   16532.64 28797.05        0.57    0
75859 159510.00 32888862.00   12264.41 28797.05        0.43    1
75795       nan 32869718.00   24218.16 24218.16        1.00    1
75518       nan 32574894.00   13304.45 13304.45        1.00    1
```

In this case, the code sums the 0.57 and 0.43 in the third row of df.

If that would not be the case, the code would go looking to third, fourth,... row of the same value in `b` - if it even exists.

This is the code for creating the `e` column

```
df['e'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.c / row.d, axis=1)
```

I tried similar for the `f` column, but I do not know how to input the `if statement` in the same code.

This is the beginning of my solution:

```
def STAcondition (row):
   if row['e'] > A :
      return 0
   if row['e'] < A :
      return 1
   return 'Other'

df['f'] =  df.apply (lambda row: STAcondition (row),axis=1)
```

Comment: The answer to the first part is simply `df['f'] = (df['e'] > a).astype(int)`. The second is trickier, you'll need a loop. And your logic doesn't quite make sense - why shouldn't the second row be 1, because the sum of it and the previous are greater than `A`?

Comment: Yes. For value 32888862 in `b` the first row in `f` is 0 and the second is 1, because the `sum` of it in `e` is greather than A, yes. Tricky. I'm trying to find the solution with the combination of `.shift`and `np.where` commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to create f in multiple steps.
If I understand correctly, your pseudo-algorithm should look like this:

- Input value to look for in b
- Is value in 'e' greater than A?

  - If true, value in f = 1
  - If false, determine if value to look for has duplicates in b. Get their indexes.

    - In the row of the last occurence of the value you were looking for, in column f, sum the values of the duplicates.
    - Is the sum greater than A?

      - If true, value in f = 1
      - If false, value in f = 0

Here's something I drew up:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy.random as npr
import numpy as np

# Dummy data
dfInit = {
    'FID_1':npr.randint(0,10,10),
    'b':npr.randint(0,10,10),
    'c':npr.randint(0,10,10),
    'd':npr.randint(0,10,10),
    'e':npr.randint(0,10,10)
}
dfIndex = np.arange(0,10)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dfInit, index=dfIndex)

# Algo
df['f'] = np.zeros(10)
A = 6

def letsMakeAnF(value):
    # check if value is in b
    if value in df['b'].unique():
        occurrenceMatch = df.loc[df['b'] == value,:] 
    else:
        print('value not in b series')
        return

    if occurrenceMatch['e'].iloc[0] > A:
        df['f'].ix[occurrenceMatch.index[0]] == 1
    else:
        if np.sum(occurrenceMatch['b']) > A:
            df['f'].ix[occurrenceMatch.index[-1]] = 1

#Generate random 'wanted' values
values = [npr.randint(0, 10) for x in range(10)]

#Iterate over the values and modify the DF. Note that in this case
#df is a global variable
for value in values:
   letsMakeAnF(value)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I get an error for `loc` - IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds. i like the logic of it, just have to fix the error first

Comment: But in this case you fixed the values in 'b' with 'value', which is different throughout df.

Comment: I think I know why you're getting the error. Is the 'value' present in 'b'? If not the occurrenceMatch is an empty DF and that breaks the algo
Maybe that case should be caught before executing the rest.

Comment: If you need to iterate over different 'values', you can always refactor the code into a function with 'value' as a param and loop over the values you need! I just wanted to keep the anwser as simple as possible so we could get to the point :)

Comment: Would you please give an example how to refactor the code into a function with 'value' as a param and loop over the values in a column in this example?

Comment: Edited. If you need to iterate over all the values in the 'b' series, just do `values = [df['b'].values]`

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to understand your proposition, since the results of a random df are not in line with your algorithm. For example: For `A=3` and value in `b` equal to `8` and value in `e` equal to `8`, the value in `f` is equal to `0`, which should be 1, since 8 > 3 and this is the only row with value 8 in `b`

Comment: Sorry, got busy with work yesterday. Since you accepted the answer, I'm guessing it worked?

Comment: I accepted it since it gave me a way to my final solution. Without it, I'd probably still be wandering around...